# Catch-all DNS record

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, wildcard

**Intro**

Our users have the ability to buy a domain (eg: user1.com) and make it point to out website, (eg: example.com), by simply pointing user1.com to ns1/ns2.example.com .

**Issue**

So far everything's good, however, example.com does not like this; we need to set up WHM/cpanel to make the server accept user1.com . Problem is, we'd rather made this automatic, possibly without having to use WHM API.

**The question**

We need some sort of "catch-all" wildcard entry so that we capture all of our user's possible domains.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after searching and get a flat "no" from HostGator, I seem to have found what I need.
This is called parked domains, and thanks to WHM/cpanel, they can be created and managed through API.

More info here:
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/XmlApi#DNS_functions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bind, you just need to generate a new zonefile and drop it into the appropriate directory (remember to update the sn in the SOA) then send bind a HUP, e.g.

```
kill -HUP `cat /var/run/named/named.pid`
```

However if you are bypassing the control panel then you'll need to think about how you allow the user to maintain the details.

C.

Comment: Sorry, sounds a lot of chinese to me...except the HUP part. Thought I should mention I'm no seasoned sysadmin :). Edit: I know what bind is but I don't know what you mean by zone file nor updating SOA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtual hosting you can have the default domain point to example.com

Now all anything hits example.com ip addess will load example.com unless there is a vhost entry for it.

Add a server alias in example.com vhost file for user1.com - will show example.com as user1.com